# Manipulate the Value of Variable inside String

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have Stored a String in My ApplicationSettings  as 
Settings name : Temp
Value : Test String & a 
Datatype: String

**In Vb.net Code:**

```
Dim a = 0
Dim str = My.Settings.Temp
```

Current Output of the str is **Test String & a** 
But I Need the output as **Test String 0**(&a should be replace with the value of a) 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use variable names as placeholder in strings. That is just a source for nasty errors in future if someone changes the variable name to somewhat more readable than `a`. _Nasty_ because they will not cause compiler errors, probably not even runtime errors but - worst case - a silent incorrect result.

Comment: I have 15 fixed variables.  Dynamically i need to change the String which is to be built. Some Cases I need to build a String with 2 variables sometimes 3 some times 1. How can i achieve this  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the string.format() method.
As an example:

```
Value : Test String {0}

Dim str = string.Format(My.Settings.Temp, a)

Result is "Test String 0".
```

String.Format() is extremely useful for such scenarios. You can add an unlimited number of different values to a string, as long as you increase the number in the brackets {}.

Comment: @user1580004 Examples?

Comment: I have variables like  A,B,C but i May use B alone some time SomeTime A&B like This. In this case how to use that??

Comment: put the correct variable in the Format() method or use something like string.Format("use the second {1} variable here only", 1 ,2 ) will result in "use the second 2 variable here only"